# How to change php variable on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
    var randomColorFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    };
    var randomColor = function(opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
    };

    var config = '<div id='humidity'>'{
        type: 'line',
        data: {

            labels: <?php echo $json_array1; ?>,

            datasets: [{
                label: "",
                data: <?php echo $json_array; ?>,
            }]
        },

        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title:{
                display:true,
                text:'Chart'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {

                }
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'dataset'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Month'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Humidity'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        suggestedMin: -10,
                        suggestedMax: 250,
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    $.each(config.data.datasets, function(i, dataset) {
        dataset.borderColor = randomColor(0.4);
        dataset.backgroundColor = randomColor(0.5);
        dataset.pointBorderColor = randomColor(0.7);
        dataset.pointBackgroundColor = randomColor(0.5);
        dataset.pointBorderWidth = 1;
    });

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

In this code I want to change `$json_array` to some other array `$json_array2` on mouse click. How can I achieve it? The `$json_array` contains the values fetched from the database.

Comment: There is a legand they say *Ajax*

Comment: php is a server side language, you cant change the variable without reloading the pages

Comment: I wrote up an answer that would be helpful to the poster, but before I could post it the submit btn became disabled, and now `Post and Answer` is gone.  My answer is more specific to this problem than the one marked as duplicate and I want to help; what do I do with my answer?

Comment: @BeetleJuice answer to the original post?

Comment: @Vlanzyvinz I'd love to but the answer button is disabled.

Comment: @BeetleJuice answer this part to that post.

Comment: @BeetleJuice mail me - aygarg.in@gmail.com

Comment: @AyushGarg . I just did. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP** is *server-side* and **jQuery** (JS) is *client-side* language, you can't change PHP variable after it executes.

You can use **AJAX**, to load new data.

Comment: This should be a comment , answer should be detailed and knowledgable, answer should be given , if you have an example for to show to the op about how he can achieve that.

Comment: I disagree. I think it's an answer to the question raised. Q: "how to change php variable on mouseclick?" A: "You can use AJAX to load new data".  It may not be enough to solve the issue; if so the OP is free to select another answer. But it does answer the question, and gives enough info for an enterprising OP to find out how to do what's needed.

Comment: I agree with the points raised by BeetleJuice and find Arsh being harsh with those downvotes.

Comment: @PockeTiger I see what you did there

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a variable directly in PHP with a mouse click, PHP runs in your server, you only have access to PHP code until it runs in your server and returns the response (usually HTML).

If you want to send data to the back end though (maybe to store in the database), you can do that with Ajax.

Here are a couple of great tutorials:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: This should be a comment , answer should be detailed and knowledgable, answer should be given , if you have an example for to show to the op about how he can achieve that.

Comment: @ArshSingh Thanks, just added a couple of links.